# Count Down - Java Script

Tags: javascript

It's a countdown code that I modified it, 
I want the countdown don't show zero variants like real countdown systems,
and **I want it in java syntax not with jquery libs!**

but **What is wrong with this part of code that not working?**

```
else if (weeks < 1 && day < 1) {
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + 'hrs '+ minutes + 'mins ' +  seconds + 'secs';}
```

**Complete HTML doc:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var end = new Date('Jan 29, 2017 15:37:25');

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var _week = _day * 7;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }

        var weeks = Math.floor(distance / _week);
        var days = Math.floor((distance % _week) / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);


        if (weeks < 1) {
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ' + hours + 'hrs '+ minutes + 'mins ' +  seconds + 'secs';
            }

        else if (days < 1) {
                var days = Math.floor(distance/ _day);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ' + hours + 'hrs '+ minutes + 'mins ' +  seconds + 'secs';
        }

        else if (weeks < 1 && day < 1) {
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + 'hrs '+ minutes + 'mins ' +  seconds + 'secs';

        }

        else { document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = weeks + 'weeks ' + days + 'days ' + hours + 'hrs '+ minutes + 'mins ' +  seconds + 'secs';}
        }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);

</script>
<p id="countdown"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which role is playing java in this question??

Comment: where is your java code?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are different languages. Also *"it's not working"* isn't a clear problem statement, right now this is off-topic.

Comment: Also note what `else if` means here, that only triggers if the previous `if` or `else if` was false. Think about this logically, it's not possible for `else if (weeks < 1 && day < 1)` to ever return `true` with your structure.

Comment: Yes it is a straight-forward logic issue in the javascript shown. The 'java' part is irrelevant here.

Comment: The confusion here would have disappeared if you had said `and I want it in native javascript not with jquery libs! ` since Java and JavaScript are two very different things as has been pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't reach your if statement...

`if (weeks < 1 )` will swallow before 'if (weeks < 1 && days < 1)` ...

Switch your if so the test for 'if (weeks < 1 && days < 1)`comes first. Also you are using`day`instead of`days`. Also, don't declare your`days` twice - not good practice though it isn't causing your problem.

More likely you want to get rid of your `else` in that statement.

Here's what you want:

```
   if (weeks < 1) {
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ' + hours + 'hrs '+ minutes + 'mins ' +  seconds + 'secs';
    }

    else if (days < 1) {
        days = Math.floor(distance/ _day);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ' + hours + 'hrs '+ minutes + 'mins ' +  seconds + 'secs';
    }

    if (weeks < 1 && days < 1) {
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + 'hrs '+ minutes + 'mins ' +  seconds + 'secs';
```

You have a number of issues - for example you have `day` instead of `days` in your one if branch.  Paste this code in place of what you have for the if and you should be a lot closer to what you want.

Here's what mine looks like with these coding changes:

`10hrs 21mins 56secs`

Here's the code to use in place of what you have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
    var end = new Date('Jan 29, 2017 15:37:25');

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var _week = _day * 7;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }

        var weeks = Math.floor(distance / _week);
        var days = Math.floor((distance % _week) / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);


        if (weeks < 1) {
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ' + hours + 'hrs '+ minutes + 'mins ' +  seconds + 'secs';
        }

        else if (days < 1) {
            days = Math.floor(distance/ _day);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ' + hours + 'hrs '+ minutes + 'mins ' +  seconds + 'secs';
        }

        if (weeks < 1 && days < 1) {
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + 'hrs '+ minutes + 'mins ' +  seconds + 'secs';

        }

        else { document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = weeks + 'weeks ' + days + 'days ' + hours + 'hrs '+ minutes + 'mins ' +  seconds + 'secs';}
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);

</script>
<p id="countdown"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Rare That's because you didn't properly explain the problem. If you want the solution you are looking for you need to explain the problem with your code.

Comment: its a simple code, there is nothing to explain more,

Comment: Answer was updated. Have you tried it? Replace your if with the code above and it will give you what you want I believe.

Comment: i want to hide weeks and days if both are zero value!

Comment: And if you try what I suggest, that is what you get!

Comment: Let me paste in the entire code. If you use this instead of yours (there were several typos and logic issues) it will give you the display the way you want.